# Glide preload only works if size is specified

Tags: android, android-glide

I have an app with a long feed of images. I want to preload the upcoming images so the users sees less (ideally no) delay when the images come on screen.

I've been trying different variants of preload() and downloadOnly(), and the only combination that seems to work is having both preload and load use the exact same size parameters.

Preloading:

```
Glide.with(AbstractFeedFragment.this)                                               
    .load(picture.getUrl())
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
    .preload();
```

The preload() here is the same as using preload(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL, Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL)

Loading the actual image into the ImageView when it comes on screen:

```
requestManager
    .load(url)
    // Use the same dimensions used as when preloading.
    .override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL, Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL)
    .placeholder(placeholderColor)
    .error(R.color.image_fallback_bg)
    .dontTransform()
    .into(imageView);
```

If I remove the override or dontTransform methods, the image gets downloaded a second time when it comes on screen (even though I just preloaded it).

Am I doing something wrong? My understanding was that DiskCacheStrategy.ALL would place the original image in the cache, which would then be retrieved and resized when displaying it for real.

Is there a way to load the image without having the specify the SIZE_ORIGINAL when actually displaying it? If I understand it correctly this means I am now displaying the image at full size instead of at the correct size for my ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

Use DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE for both the preload and your request (for remote images).

RESULT is the default in Glide 3, which would require that your request have exactly the same transformation, width, and height as your preload.

Using ALL in your preload will essentially cache the same data twice (because no transformation is specified and you're using SIZE_ORIGINAL which would prevent downsampling).